# Django URL defaults to undefined location

Tags: django, python-2.7, google-chrome, django-urls

I created my first Django project, but when I go to the localhost address (`http://127.0.0.1:8000`), it immediately redirects to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/catalog` and gives the `Page not found at /catalog/ 404 error`. Based on the code I've written, I expected it to go to `/index`. The `catalog` url is not defined anywhere in my project, and that word appears nowhere in any of the associated files. Here's the relevant code:

urls.py:

```
from django.views.generic import RedirectView
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls), 
    url(r'^index/', include('portal.urls')),
    url(r'^$', RedirectView.as_view(url='/index/', permanent=True)),
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

portal/urls.py:

```
from . import views 
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.indexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    url(r'^portal/(?P<pk>\d+)$', views.mapView.as_view(), name='portal'),
]
```

I have been using the Chrome browser to do all this. When I tried on Firefox, it worked correctly (i.e. when I typed in `http://127.0.0.1:8000` it redirected to `/index/`). Regardless of browser, if I go to `127.0.0.1:8000/index` everything appears as it should.

The only thing I can think of that would create this problem is that I went through the MDN [Django tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Tutorial_local_library_website) that did use the `catalog` url, so I deleted all history from Chrome that involved `localhost`, but the problem persists. Seems like it should work regardless of history or cookies, anyways.

What part of my code isn't strong enough to override the browser history, cookies, or whatever is creating this problem? (I'm new to Django, so let me know if more code snippets would be useful).

Comment: If you have a habit of issuing a permanent redirect on `/`, then I bet the redirect to `/catalog/` is cached by your browser, and you just need to clear your cache (and maybe rethink if you want to use a permanent redirect).

Comment: That's kind of what I was thinking, but I thought I was telling it to redirect to `/index`?

Comment: can you paste your `RedirectView ` code here?

Comment: also I don't think `RedirectView.as_view(url='/index/', permanent=True)` is the correct way to redirect

Comment: @Bird Like you said, a previous project used `/catalog/`, so if that was a permanent redirect it's likely that is still cached by your browser. The request won't even reach Django if a permanent redirect is cached.